# Process to wait for DB(handle Operational error)

Tags: python, django, database, orm

Problem: 
I have a django process which talks to DB and gets the result. Before starting the process, I have code to check if db connection is successful or not using `connection.ensure_connection()`. If it db connection is established, then the process will start or the process will be waiting for db to get connected.

Now Let's say I have the process started. The process has total 5 queries listed below:

```
ModelOne.objects.get(pk=1)
ModelOne.objects.get(pk=2)
ModelOne.objects.get(pk=3)
ModelOne.objects.get(pk=4)
ModelOne.objects.get(pk=5)
```

First two queries have successfully run and then the DB goes down. Now while executing `ModelOne.objects.get(pk=3)` process throws an `Operational Error: Connection refused`.

Is there any way where if suddenly DB goes down while a process is running, then pause the process, ensure db connection is established and resume the process?

Python -- 2.7, Django -- 1.11